# hdf5: Chunking increases datasize up to 100%

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py, chunking

I'm currently writing a python script in order to concatenate lots of small and non-chunked .h5 files (~7MB each). The total disk space for all the files is several GB.

Each file has two datasets (uint8 & float32 type) with shape (rows, 11, 13, 18) & (rows, 6). The number of rows for each file is slightly different (~thousands). In order to concatenate the files, I have to create a chunked output dataset (maxshape).

Now, I've noticed that the resulting output file consumes a lot more disk space than for the single files, e.g. 7MB+7MB = 22MB.

In order to simplify the issue, one can also just use n = 1 files for concatenating, i.e. convert the file from a non-chunked to a chunked .h5 file.
If I manually force a small chunksize=2, the result is 7MB (unchunked) -> 7MB (chunked).
However, if I increase the chunksize to more than a thousand, the required disk space is nearly doubled: 7MB (unchunked) ->  14MB (chunked).

Now I really wonder, why is the difference between the chunked and non chunked .h5 file so large?

Here are the h5stat outputs of the chunksize=2 and chunksize=2500 files:
https://pastebin.com/Gg3LGQkk (2), https://pastebin.com/jUbfemp0 (2500).
Looks like not the metadata, but the raw data is the problem.

Is the increased disk size normal for a chunked .h5 file? And if yes, does it make sense to store my data with chunks? Later on, I'm reading the large, concatenated .h5 file row by row, so I wonder if a non-chunked .h5 file (smaller in disk size) would be a lot slower in I/O.

A code snippet with h5py implementation:

```
import h5py
#remove file_2 for the simplest non-chunked -> chunked conversion
file_list = [file_1.h5, file_2.h5] # not chunked, e.g. 2866 and 2825 rows
file_output = h5py.File('test.h5', 'w')

cum_rows_list = [0, 2866, 5691] # cumulative number of rows for the input

for n, input_file_name in enumerate(file_list):

    print 'Processing file ' + file_list[n]
    input_file = h5py.File(input_file_name, 'r')

    for folder_name in input_file:

        folder_data = input_file[folder_name] 
        if n == 0:
            # first file; create the dummy dataset with no max shape
            maxshape = (None,) + folder_data.shape[1:]

            # create chunked output dataset
            output_dataset = file_output.create_dataset(
            folder_name, data=folder_data, maxshape=maxshape, 
            chunks=(2500,) + folder_data.shape[1:])
            output_dataset.resize(cum_rows_list[-1], axis=0)

        else:
            # not important for only one file
            ...

    file_output.flush()

file_output.close()
```

**Update:**
As yar has pointed out in the comments, the difference in file size is based on padding due to the specified chunksize.

Comment: This is a `hdf5` issue, not one particular to the `h5py` interface.  There's much more discussion of chunking there.  Of hand I couldn't find discussion of changes in file size, but it doesn't surprise me that size is noticeably larger.  Your use of a resizeable dataset may exaggerate the effect.

Comment: Well, I wasn't completely sure if the root of the problem was a programming fault by myself. So I'm particularly concerned about I/O for reading row-by-row, since I'm feeding the dataset data (set of arrays) to a deep neural network ('images'). I guess for multi GB data I should use chunking anyways if disk space is not a problem, right?

Comment: A recent SO discussion on a related topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227009/h5py-chunking-on-resizable-dataset

Comment: Might it be, that through chunking you get padding? e.g. you need 1200 rows, and have chunk size 1000. The resulting file will have 2000 rows, since a full chunk must be saved.

Comment: @yar You were totally right. If I set the chunksize to the average number of rows for each file, the output file uses practically the same amount of disk space as the sum of the single files.  
With automated chunking, 600 concatenated files took nearly 6GB, and now it's down to 4.1GB (600*~7MB).
Looks like the automated chunking took a very large chunk size, since the overhead was so large.

Comment: Now I just need to consider I/O performance for my use case. Later on, I'm reading my data row-by-row in batches of e.g. 100 rows. I guess I'd get the fastest I/O with setting the chunksize to 100 as well, right?